# ASP.Net SiteMap URL Distinction

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap

I have a Web Application that I have inherited it contains a page that decides which URL you need to visit based upon the state of an object passed into it.

The URL's are held within the sitemap and there is a method to retrieve all of them.

```
private Dictionary<string, string> GetUrls() {
    var urls = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var provider = SiteMap.Provider;

    var page1 = provider.FindSiteMapNodeFromKey("page1");
    var page2 = provider.FindSiteMapNodeFromKey("page2");


    if (page1 == null || page2 == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Pages not found in sitemap");
    }

    urls["page1URL"] = page1.Url.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    urls["page2URL"] = page2.Url.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    return urls;
}
```

unfortunately within this method, page1 and page2 are always null

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" enableLocalization="true">
    <siteMapNode resourceKey="Concessions" rule="AllowRead">
        <siteMapNode url="/page1.aspx" resourceKey="page1" rule="AllowAuthorised"/>
        <siteMapNode url="/page2.aspx" resourceKey="page2" rule="AllowAuthorised"/>
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

I have tried to debug through this process but I am not getting anywhere near the problem.
So to recap I need this method to return the URLS of the pages defined within the sitemap.

Comment: The remarks section in the docs for the Find method are interesting (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapprovider.findsitemapnodefromkey.aspx) - what provider does it use?

Comment: yes I saw this too the "always returns null in all cases" but how then do I get the URL, please forgive my newb-ness

Comment: I think your problem may be that you are using the default  XmlSiteMapProvider - looking at that the key is the URL itself. So you need to either pass in "/page1.aspx" or implement your own provider and override FindSiteMapNodeFromKey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely unrelated error, sorry for wasting your time